# Next.js list scroll working only after reloading page

Tags: html, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am working on a next.js web project.
On one page I have a background image covering the whole screen and a list.
By hovering on the list items the background image changes.
The list is scrollable, the background image should not move by scrolling the list.

In my solution, the scrolling output works but not all the time. After navigating to other pages in the project an then coming back to this page, the scroll only works after reloading the page.

Do you have any ideas why I have to reload the page?

Here is my page with the scroll:

```
``export default function Page() {
 // .... stuff for the list text and hover effects
return (
<>
<div className="absolute justify-center inset-0 bg-cover bg-center transition-all duration-500 ease-in bgImageFilterWork" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${currentBg})`}}>

<div className="pt-60 justify-center h-screen absolute z-10 overflow-y-auto w-screen text-center" >
 
<ul className='list-none inline-block pb-44' >
     
{paintingNames.map((item,index) => (
<Link key={item.id} href={`...`} passHref>
<h2  className={`paintingNameText bg-gradient-to-r ${from} ${via} ${to} text-transparent bg- clip-text bg-300% hover:animate-gradient hover:from-orange-700 hover:via-blue-700 ${activeIndex === index ? 'animate-gradient via-blue-700 from-orange-700' : ''}`}
ref={el => nameRefs.current[index] = el} // Add ref for each name
key={item.id}
onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(nameRefs.current[item.id],item.imageUrl)} >{item.name}. </h2>
</Link>
))}
        
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</>
)
}

// and the css class for the image:
.bgImageFilterWork::before {
@apply bg-cover bg-center h-screen w-full absolute;
content: "";
background-color: rgba(242, 224, 190, 0.73);
z-index: 1;
backgroundattachment: fixed;
}`
```

`

I tried to change the overflow class, but then the result is that the whole page with background image scrolls too.

I tested it on chrome and safari, same behaviour.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't compatible with Lenis Scroll, which I used in my root page.